# Change object state in different point in program

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented, encapsulation

This is not about whether or not getters/setters are wrong.  I understand its impact to encapsulation and that question has been raised here and SO several times already.  I also do not want to just ask for an example of how to change object state as all the examples I've seen are so naive that they're only practical for simple objects. I do want to ask for an example on more specific terms so that I can make the rubber meet the road in a very practical way concerning this concept.

**The Question**

How can an object's state can be changed when one of its data objects cannot be initialized upon construction of the parent object to begin with?

**More Specifically**

Even more specifically, I have this situation where I am defining a domain entity for an API that is representative of a data entity in a third-party system whose data is stored in files.  (For this question I'm using domain/data entity to distinguish the difference between the two).  This is a requirement to ensure loose coupling between layers and the fact that though the entities are representative of each other, they are not one-to-one representations, more representative in principle.  The client code will be able to create these domain entities and commit an internal transaction designed to coordinate the write to the files.  One of the domain entity's properties is a Handle object that contains the third-party data entity's handle ID so that any later changes to the data entity in the file can be easily and quickly coordinated.  This handle ID can't be set to the domain entity until it captures it in the data access layer on the first write.

**In a nutshell**

So in a scenario where the object cannot obtain all its state on construction, but get the rest at a different point in the program (and maybe even a totally different application layer), how should this look without breaking principles of encapsulation and Tell-Don't-Ask?

Btw... I'm using c#, so any comparable example along these lines would help me better relate.

Comment: The only way you can create an object and hand it some state later is to... create an object, and hand it some state later.  You can do that by calling a method or setting some properties on the object after instantiation.

Comment: Please note that asking for an example is [off-topic](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6487). I reworded your question to avoid the "resource request" verbiage.

Comment: What exactly you are asking? You can assign the handle by defining a method such as `public void AssignHandleID(int idOfHandle)`. Does that not solve your problem?

Comment: @Snowman: Thank you very much.  I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @DavidPacker There is a Handle object that internally contains the ID.  When the domain entity is created, it has an uninitialized Handle object.  In the data access layer, when written, the Handle object will be initialized.  I don't want to expose the ability to AssignHandleID(int idOfHandle) to the client since that breaks encapsulation.  So I'm asking how to control change of an object's state without exposing it to the client.

Comment: @DavidPacker: I'm trying to handle encapsulation well with this and there's a lot of articles out there saying not to expose getter/setter methods since they can allow the client to change the state of the object.  So my goal is to figure out how to allow the state to be changed for those uninitialized objects.  Handle is just an example since that's applicable to what I'm working on now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  But doesn't that break encapsulation?

Comment: You're basically asking us how to let the client change the state of the object without allowing the client to change the state of the object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I guess if you want to look at it that way.  I really do want that hidden upwards in terms of application layers.  The client side using this API should not be aware of a SetHandle(Handle h) method.  Yet, down in the DAL, it should.  I just figured there had to be some kind of design approach to doing this that is more true to the OO spirit of things.  There's been plenty of articles that say leaving such things open is a sign of a bad design.  If so, then I'm asking how should even such an issue as this be addressed in a good way?

Comment: Have a look at [Data Transfer Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), or Fowler's [Anemic Domain Model article](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).  Even Fowler admits that sometimes you have to pass around an open data object.  Encapsulation and "Tell, don't ask" are just principles, not laws.

Comment: Would it be possible not to pass the mutable entity object itself and _as itself_ to the client?

Comment: Maybe `domanInstance.New(IdHandleType handleObject)` returning a new object of that same type with merged state. If static, then: `DomainClass.New( DomainClass instance, IdHandleType handleObject)`.

Comment: It sounds like your object may not technically have a "state" per-say because everything is contained by your files. Also, were you provided some API that you are trying to wrap? If you can confirm either of these things I might be able to provide an answer close enough to what you want that is comparable to something I have dealt with over the years.